# Solve the Equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1  \\
        1 & 1   \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
        v_1  \\
        v_2   \\
        \end{Bmatrix}=
\begin{Bmatrix}
        0  \\
        0   \\
        \end{Bmatrix}$$

How can i solve this ?

I found it $$v_1+v_2=0$$   $$v_1+v_2=0$$ .

So i can't solve it for $v_1$ and $v_2$ .

Comment: what about $v_1 = 1, v_2 = -1?$

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @abel How did you solve it ? I can't  see the  mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have $1$ equation in two unknowns. Let $v_2= t$, where $t\in \mathbb R$. Then $v_1 = -v_2 = -t$.

So there are infinitely many solutions, all of which can be represented by $$V = \begin{pmatrix} -t\\t\end{pmatrix} = t\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ again, where $t$ can take any value in the reals (assuming that's the field on which $V$ is defined.)

NOTE: You could just as easily set $t = v_1 \implies v_2 = -t = -v_1$.

Comment: Why $v_2=-t=-1$ ? why $-1$ ?

Comment: We know $v_1 = -v_2$. So letting $t$ represent any real number whatsoever, we put one of $v_1$ or $v_2 = t,$ so the other is then $-t$. Remember that $t$ can be any real number. If  $v_2 = t$, $v_1$ has to be $-t$. So we can list the entries of our vector as $-t, t$, or we can multiply the vector $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ by the scalar $t$, which then represents *every* solution to the equation.

Answer (score 1):

because you have only two variables $v_1, v_2$ you can think of the equation $v_1 + v_2 = 0$ as a line through the origin with slope $-1.$  you have one line in the plane because the second equation does not anything more to this line. any point on this line is a solution. all solutions are given by $v_1 = t, v_2 = -t$ where you can take $t$ to be anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinite solutions. For every $v_1$ there is a $v_2$ which is negative of it.

Comment: So i can arbitrarily choose $v_1=100$ and $v_2=-100$ ?

Comment: @tree Yes, pick an arbitrary $v_1\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $(v_1,v_2) = (v_1,-v_1)$ is a solution.